# How does WPF optimise the layout / rendering cycle?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, performance

**How does WPF optimize the Layout / Rendering cycle in a highly volatile application?**

For example, imagine I invalidate a custom control twice in quick succession, will it render twice? Are there performance issues when Data/Property update-rates are faster than main render rate?

Answer (score 7):

Based on my experience, I can say that no it will no render twice if it's fast enought.
I'm not 100% sure, but this is why i think this:

We had a really heavy application (thousands of controls), it was an aircraft cockpit, all in wpf, each button, switch, screen were movable by gesture, or mouse.

The cockpit was 10 000 pixels by 10 000 pixels, and implemented a Zoom in/Zoom out (with mouse wheel), panning when right mouse button clicked.

Before optimization, it was very laggy, slow, so each "Zoom" step, or "Pan" step took about 1 second

If I Zoom 1 time (Zoom * 1.2 for example), it took 1 second

If I Zoom 10 times (Zoom * 1.2 X 10), it does not takes 10 seconds, it takes probably like 2 seconds depending on the speed you scroll, and it does not render each "zoom step" it render only the last one...

Comment: Wow.... 10k x 10k... with zoom and thousands of controls... that is a helluva UI..

Comment: This cockpit is use for basic training only, for student to 'navigate' into the cockpit without having the real one, used in the training class when the teacher explain panels, explain witch button do this and that... it's not used for a complete simulation

Comment: That is interesting, I would presume the properties the controls were bound-to would be updating much faster than 1/sec. I would be interested to see, when rendering the entire screen, if there is a noticeable difference between no-property-updates and regular-property-updates (i.e. several per second)

Comment: @mlemay how did you optimize it?