# map maker application

Tags: c#

I have created a somewhat complete application which allows me to create a map (.txt file with information about all the points of the map), load it and draw it.

My solution for this was, inside the windows forms application, to put a panel (since I need to be able to move on map) and inside that panel pictureboxes(since I want to put a background image and image on them) that represent points of map in size 50x50 pixels. The problem I am facing now is increased load time for my application, since I am loading pictures into the pictureboxes...

Does anyone have any alternative suggestion to what I have been attempting?
Visual representation might help:

[image: NOTE: Pictureboxes only have background color here...]

The code, as requested: (well, some of it)

```
    private void Load_Map()
    {
        for (int i = Y - 12; i < Y + 12; i++)
        {
            if ((i >= 0) & (i < Int32.Parse(MP.Mheight)))
            {
                string Line = xline[i];
                for (int j = X - 12; j < X + 12; j++)
                {
                    if ((j >= 0) & (j < Int32.Parse(MP.Mwidth)))
                    {
                        int X = i * Int32.Parse(MP.Mwidth) + j;
                        int Z = Int32.Parse(Line[j].ToString());
                        Map_Location[X] = Z;

                        Color H = new Color();
                        Map_Point(j, i, Map_Height(Z, H), 50);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Creating points:

```
    private void Map_Point(int X, int Y, Color H, int Point_Size)
    {
        PictureBox MP = new PictureBox();
        MP.Name = Map_Coordinates(X, Y);
        MP.Size = new Size(Point_Size, Point_Size);
        MP.Location = new Point(Y * (Point_Size + 1) + 4, X * (Point_Size + 1) + 4);
        MP.BackColor = H;

        Control MW = this.Controls["WorldMap"];
        MW.Controls.Add(MP);

    }
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code that you are using to load pictures into the picture boxes? It's hard to provide an alternate solution without knowing what you've tried already.

Comment: `Does anyone have any alternative suggestion to what I have been attempting?` - Yes I do, switch to WPF. winforms is too slow and crappy, and requires a bunch of hacks when it comes to doing anything graphics-intensive.

Comment: tnw there's lot of code, but sure I ll share... @HighCore I will look into it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll be better off creating a custom control by deriving from `System.Windows.Forms.Control` and overriding the `OnPaint` method and doing your own drawing and handling click events yourself.

Using a large number of WinForms controls the way you're doing is an exercise in pain, as WinForms will create a `hWnd` object for each control, and WinForms doesn't scale too well, unfortunately.

Comment: +1 for `WinForms doesn't scale too well`. winforms doesn't even scale.

Comment: I see, maybe some more info on this? or should I just look for guides myself? :P

Comment: The situation sucks really - WPF is great for data-binding, resolution-independence, and fluid animations, but suffers from poor startup performance and UI cohesiveness with the parent OS, whereas WinForms is Flicker-ville and is painful to animate. Why won't Microsoft release DirectUI? :(

Comment: @Dai Im not sure what you mean by UI cohesiveness and all that stuff, but a couple of days ago I seen this one guy posted an answer about a 10k x 10k sized WPF application with thousands of controls supporting mouse and touch. It was an aircraft cockpit simulator.

Comment: @Dai [here is the answer I mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550403/how-does-wpf-optimise-the-layout-rendering-cycle)

Comment: @HighCore WPF does not use any "native" or OS-provided controls (like the Windows Common Controls library). Instead it re-implements all of the controls itself, which as with Java, means they don't have exactly the same UX as the native OS. For example, WPF does not support custom Visual Styles, and WPF's text rendering isn't the same as GDI (at least until recently when they fixed it). It suffers from uncanny-valley syndrome. However, even if you're developing an entirely custom UI where this doesn't matter (e.g. a game) it still suffers from slow a initialization process.

Comment: @Dai `"(at least until recently when they fixed it)"` - Wrong. "Recently" is not 2010, when .Net 4.0 was released. That's not "Recently" to me. And by the way, yeah, WPF below 4.0 does not count to me.

Comment: @HighCore pfft, mere semantics :) 2010 isn't that long ago considering WPF has been around since 2005.

Comment: @Dai you're right. I wonder wth microsoft decided to switch all it's efforts to re-do everything in WinRT instead of fixing the revelant issues still pending in WPF. still, winforms is no longer an option for almost anything.

Comment: Uhm... you can make winforms scale... you can pick up the client size and scale your sizes accordingly...  int T = ClientRectangle.Height; or width and use it accordingly if your program is locked and set as fullscreen, a painfull process indeed but still, possible...

Comment: @AntonioTehSumtin That's not what I mean by "scale" - in this case "scaling" refers to the ability of a platform or framework to handle large amounts of data or instances. Specifically WinForms tends to choke if you want to have more than 100 controls in a Form, and very-nested controls don't tend to play nice either.

Comment: @Dai I see, I've been limiting the number of controls in winforms for exact reason :D, on other note, I tried playing with WPF last two days... so far, I hate it. There are no pictureboxes, there are images, which can't have color or click events... yaaay, trying to figure this out...

Comment: I played with WPF these few weeks, it's a bit different but I think I got it a bit :) Still didn't get the chance to test preformance of my application since I didn't have enough time to rebuild it just yet, thank you for advice.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `System.Drawing.Graphics`

Here are the [MSDN Tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/sfwzeec0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for it.

It has a method called `DrawImage` , which you can use instead of a picture box.  For the grid you should be drawing it as a rectangle with a color for the background and vertical/horizontal lines to make the grid.

Comment: grid is just an empty space between images, I will look into tutorial but more importantly, can I draw on top of the created image once I make it that way?